# cant click on password field using javascript (using selenium + java), can you help pls?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image]

here password input field needs to entered with an value, however I tried options with javascript and xpath and nothing works. any help here is appreciated. thanks.

-- tried this using js:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']/following::object[@id='pw_obj']"));
String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+"123456"+"')"; 
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, myElement);
```

also using without js:

```
WebElement pw = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='pw_obj']"));
pw.sendKeys("23456");
```

html:

```
<li>
    <div>
        <span class="login_left" id="login_pw">Password:</span>
        <object width="148" height="22" id="pw_obj" classid="CLSID:fc0bff2d-47a5-0846-0147-a5084e8b000e" codebase="/xxxx/yyyyyy/signin/CTPCryp.CAB#version=1,0,0,00" vspace="1" style="border: 1px solid rgb(171, 173, 179); border-image: none;" onkeydown="pw_objKeyDownFunc(event);">
            <PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="3916">
            <PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="582">
        </object>
        <input name="pw" type="hidden">
        <input name="ssicFlag" type="hidden" value="0">
        <input name="flowCtx.defaultRoleId" type="hidden" value="">
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and the error?

Comment: Edit your question and add your code there. Also format it so that others can read it easily.

Comment: thanks @Shawn, without js, i get below error
 org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element cannot be interacted with via the keyboard because it is not focusable

Comment: Did it work with JS?

Comment: No, no action and cursor remain in the username field.

Comment: Can you share the URL if it is public?

Comment: sorry its not public,

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead. You can keep the screenshot since it shows the UI but edit your question and post the HTML as text, properly formatted.

Comment: sure JeffC, html also updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. sure it can be better but these kind of fields, I think this will better fit.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress('1')
robot.keyPress('2')
robot.keyPress('3')
```

or

```
String pwd = "123456"
Robot robot = new Robot();

for(int c=0;c<pwd.length();c++){
   robot.keyPress(pwd.charAt(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML you've posted, the below should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("pw_obj")).sendKeys("password")
```

If it doesn't, it's likely in an IFRAME, etc. but we can't tell given the limited HTML posted.

---

Second attempt...

I would try setting the value on the hidden INPUT directly using JS.

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='pw']"));
String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','" + "123456" + "')";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, myElement);
```

Comment: It uses a frame, which i have switched already before this. also tried with and without switching frame (there is only one frame in dom)

Comment: So did this work? If not, what was the error message?

Comment: "element cannot be interacted with via the keyboard because it is not focusable" error thrown.

Comment: @Gireesh I've added an alternate approach that I think will work.

Comment: Hi JeffC, scripts just passed without any error and value not entered in to the password field.

- Also tried different options of keep //object[@id='pwd_ibj'] but the value not entered.
- Object tag actually highlights the input field of password. but not sure how do i pass values.
- Also tried your second attempt with and without switch frames. not helped.

Comment: @Gireesh Are you able to send keys to the Username field? If so, you can try sending TAB from there to put you into the Password field and then type the password? I dunno... without seeing the page, I'm kinda out of ideas.

Comment: thanks JeffC for your honest efforts, I know its bit painful without having looked at the page. however I have done this using Robot class now. sure this isnt good option, but will work for now. thank you once again for your lot of ideas.